# How do I make the emoji keyboard pop up faster

Tags: macos, keyboard, catalina, emoji

1. I am typing something in a text field
2. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show the emoji selector
3. type an emoji name
4. click the emoji I want
5. 

But the computer delay between (2) and (3) is way too long, and the first few characters of the emoji name isn't entered into the emoji search bar. The animation takes so long to finish.

How can I get rid of the emoji pop up animation so that I won't have this problem?

Or, alternatively, how can I circumvent this problem entirely and use another (equally convenient) method of inputting emoji?

Comment: What do you consider too long?  1 sec, 5 sec, 30 sec.  And what do you mean by animation?  Is that displaying the emoji screen?

Comment: @jmh yeah it pops(slides?grows?) up similar to the genie animation of minimising and opening windows to dock

Comment: @jmh currently the delay between pressing ctrl cmd space and being able to type in the emoji search bar is simply too large. I would like to make this delay feel as if it doesn't exist. If I take my typing speed of ~170 wpm and assume that's the indicator of how much time is between every single one of my keypresses, then that would mean the delay should be at most 0.07 seconds. Obviously the shorter the better.